# Trying To Merge An Object And Text In Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Another newbie question in Illustrator that I can't find on Google.

I have a object made up of a bunch of different elements. Then I overlaid text on top of it (the text hangs off the edges of the object). Now I want to put a drop shadow on the entire logo but when I do it obviously puts a drop shadow behind the object AND behind the text. I want it to all be treated as one big object so there is no drop shadow on the text that is on top of the object.

When I rasterize, it loses significan quality (as I presumed). When I try to unite, it doesn't actually unite them at all (it just gets rid of my Extrude & Bevel on the object). When I try to merge, the elements of the object go out of order and become one solid object, losing it's coloring.

I'm hoping this doesn't sound too confusing. Basically I'm just trying to merge an object and overlain text into one solid object. Thanks.

---

### EDIT

Here are pertinent photos.

The "Object":

[image]

The Elements of the Object:
[image: The Elements Of The Object]

As you can see, there is a shadow behind the text (I just want it behind the object as a whole):
[image]

When I try to merge it flattens the object (gets rid of the effects):
[image]

When I try to unite it messes up the object:
[image]

Comment: Why are you merging? That does not appear to be a case where Merge would help in any way. You need separate objects.

Comment: Yeah I've been using Photoshop for so many years and I'm still trying to wrap my head around the concepts in Illustrator (that's why I may seem lost here!). I'm basically trying to make it all one object so the drop shadow goes behind it as a whole (not for each individual letter and object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't Merge the two objects.

Remove the drop shadow from both objects.

Place the stars and text how you want them.

Select both and Group (Object > Group)

Then apply the drop shadow to the group.

(Logos shouldn't really contain drop shadows, but that's another discussion.)

Comment: Ah, super simple, thank you. (Btw I'm up for any discussion, I'm here to learn!) Thanks Scott.

Comment: You could also take a look at the Shape Builder Tool (shift+m) this can be very useful to combine shapes.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is group them together before applying the style.

Select all the objects then hit Object > Group then apply your shadow.